# "Post Your Question" and "Post Your Question And Answer"

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions

I just figured out that if you go to ask a question, and click on the "Answer your own question" checkbox at least two times in a row, fairly quickly, this is what happens:

[image]

Normally, only one of those two buttons would show up depending on what question mode you're in. I guess this problem could be easily fixed by not letting the user click too quickly. It also occurs on MSO, and right now I can't reproduce this problem on other SE sites since I don't have the rep to ask and answer my own question, but if anyone can, I'll move this question to MSE.

Comment: Yes, this is probably reproducible on all sites, since they all use the same fade transition effect. It’s probably easier to click the checkbox, then press space immediately afterwards.

Comment: @Xufox True, that works too.

Comment: If I were to fix the bug, I’d possibly disable the checkbox right after changing it, but definitely, at the same time, not make the state of the question form depend on the checkbox anymore until after the transition is finished. This means that the state the form transitions into would be decided upon the _first_ change of the checkbox and any checkbox state change after that would become irrelevant. This probably involves unbinding the event listener.

Comment: Sounds like a case of not enough jQuery

Comment: @Shog9 Or _too much_ jQuery?

Comment: Wha... No such thing!

Comment: And why did you click quickly on this? you shouldn't ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yeah you try to convince my dad to stop double clicking things that require only one click. Impossible.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Dunno, kind of felt like it :|

Comment: What happens, what?

Comment: @Xufox you wouldn't have to unbind, you could just store the state in a variable outside of the handler, then check the state variable before proceeding. If the variable is false set it to true and continue. If the variable is true, return. Once the handler logic is completed, set the variable to false again.

Comment: @TemaniAfif - As soon as you think you've built something 'idiot-proof', the world just builds a better idiot.

Answer (score 4):

The checkbox is now disabled while the form elements are animating, so you shouldn't be able to trigger this issue anymore!